Jasmine + Karma Error: Invalid configuration of route '...' One of the following must be provided: component, redirectTo, children or loadChildren
I have this component defined inside its own routing-module file, like this:
 {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'list', pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'list',
    component: BooksListContainerComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard],
    children: [
      { path: ':customerId' }
    ],
    data: {
      accessKey,
      cardContainer: false,
      noPadding: false,
    }
  }

As you can see, there are 2 ways to access this component, one of them is by adding a path param & the other one by just leaving that empty. But wasn't able to recreate both scenarios by doing test with Jasmine.
Heres what I've done so far inside the spec file:
describe('(1) BooksListContainerComponent unit test', () => {

    let fixture: ComponentFixture<BooksListContainerComponent>;
    let component: BooksListContainerComponent;
    let router: Router;

    beforeEach(async () => {
        await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [
                BooksListContainerModule,
                ReactiveFormsModule,
                RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([{
                    path: 'list',
                    children: [{
                        path: ':customerId',
                        data: null,
                        component: BooksListContainerComponent
                    }]
                }]),
            ],
            providers: [
                {
                    provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: {
                        params: of({ customerId: 'test' })
                    }
                }
            ],
            declarations: [
                BooksListContainerComponent,
                AppComponent
            ],
            schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
        }).compileComponents();
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(BooksListContainerComponent);
        router = TestBed.inject(Router);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.autoDetectChanges();
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });

    it('Should create BooksListContainerComponent', () => {
        let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(BooksListContainerComponent);
        let component = fixture.debugElement.children[0].componentInstance;
        component.customerECustCode = null;
        fixture.detectChanges();
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    })
});

Here's the full log output with the error:
Chrome 126.0.0 (Windows 10.0.0) (1) BooksListContainerComponent unit test Should create BooksListContainerComponent FAILED
        Error: Invalid configuration of route 'list/:customerId'. One of the following must be provided: component, redirectTo, children or loadChildren
            at validateNode (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/router/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/router.js:1292:1)
            at validateConfig (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/router/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/router.js:1247:1)
            at validateNode (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/router/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/router.js:1309:1)
            at validateConfig (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/router/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/router.js:1247:1)
            at Router.resetConfig (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/router/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/router.js:7462:1)
            at new Router (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/router/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/router.js:6921:1)
            at Object.setupTestingRouter [as useFactory] (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/router/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/testing.js:139:1)
            at Object.factory (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:17223:1)
            at R3Injector.hydrate (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:17053:42)
            at R3Injector.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:16803:1)

Here's all dependencies from package.json:
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.901.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~9.1.0",
    "@chiragrupani/karma-chromium-edge-launcher": "^2.2.1",
    "@types/crypto-js": "^3.1.47",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "javascript-obfuscator": "^4.0.2",
    "karma": "~4.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.3",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.8.3"
  },

Thanks
I'm just trying to make expect(component).toBeTruthy(); work

You have to modify the routing. As the error says there cannot be an empty route, it should have a component, redirectTo, children or loadChildren defined.
...
{
    path: 'list',
    canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard],
    children: [
      { path: '', component: BooksListContainerComponent, },
      { path: ':customerId', component: BooksListContainerComponent, },
    ],
    data: {
      accessKey,
      cardContainer: false,
      noPadding: false,
    }
}
...

